# IIS Rewrite - match URL overwriting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis

I'm trying to set up some 301 redirects however I'm running into trouble with the match URL statement.

This is my IISUrlRewrite.xml file:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="CAS to PAS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="/call-answering-service" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="/us/phone-answering-service" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="PAS tp CAS lp" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="/us/lp/phone-answering-service" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="/us/lp/call-answering-service" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

So the first redirect lives at `https://localhost:5001/us/call-answering-service/`
which should redirect to `https://localhost:5001/us/call-answering-service/` 
this one works fine, however, the 2nd redirect which lives at

`https://localhost:5001/us/lp/phone-answering-service/` redirects to `https://localhost:5001/us/phone-answering-service` instead of `https://localhost:5001/us/lp/call-answering-service/`

I'm assuming this is causing the first rule it matching the URL contains /call-answering-service after it gets redirected by the second rule and hits the first rule. is there a way for me to make this more explicit?

Thanks

Comment: Unless you add `us` to the first rule it will always redirect again since you cannot make it unique. Either use Rewrite instead of Redirect or simply use different urls (you are redirecting anyways)

Comment: I've added in /us/ to the start of the first rule now however I still end up getting redirected to /us/phone-answering-service for the 2nd rule

Comment: But you could try `^call-answering-service$` the `^` means that there is nothing in front, so like www.domain.com/call-answering-service and the `$` means there cannot be anything behind it for it to redirect, so www.domain.com/call-answering-service/page1 will not work.

Comment: See https://www.bisend.com/blog/top-iis-rewrite-rules and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module